# Авто запуск программы linux debian 6.3

Tags: cron, debian, linux

Авто запуск программы linux debian 6.3? При включение нужно чтобы запускалась программа. Как это реализовать?

Comment: @avengerweb, Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

Но вообще, не плохо было бы указать что знгачит после включения ?
После включения могут запускатся только сервисы/демоны.
После логина нужно запускать или просто после включения нужнор запускать службу ?

Comment: @shurik возможно, после загрузки надо запустить программу один раз. @пауку-мстителю man 5 init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прописать в /etc/[rc.local](http://rc.local)

Answer (score 1):

Можно так 
если файл в /etc/init.d/ 
то можно update-rc.d имя файла defaults
удалить update-rc.d -f имя файла remove

Answer (score 1):

Я точно не помню, но разве там нет гуя для добавления программы в автозапуск? Просто указать путь к исполняемому файлу.